# How to align Face Images using Matlab?

Tags: alignment, face-recognition

I'm looking for a face image alignment code in matlab.Can somebody please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the method that I used, may be not the only way but this is what I can think about:

1. Select an image as reference.
2. Apply  points feature algorithm. As an example, three points on left eye and three points on right eye. So now, we have `reference = [x1,y1; x2,y2; x3,y3;.....;x6,y6];`
3. Next, loop all  the images one by one, and get the points feature which are exactly at the same place as reference image. `move  = [X1,Y1; X2,Y2; X3,Y3;.....;X6,Y6]`
4. Calculate geometric transformation using:  `[tform,inlierPtsDistorted,inlierPtsOriginal] = estimateGeometricTransform(move,reference,'similarity');`.
5. Then, warp the two images as follow: `outputView = imref2d(size(referenceImage)); Ir = imwarp(probeImage,tform,'OutputView',outputView);`

### This is image shows the points between reference image and probe image are  matched:

[image]

### Reference (1st image) and the outputs:

[image][image][image][image]

This method also crop out the background and hair, since my reference image does not contain background and hair part.